# Having trouble centering my iframe due to my <style>

Tags: iframe

```
<style>
    #wrap { width: 600px; height: 390px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
    #frame { width: 800px; height: 520px; border: 1px solid black; }
    #frame {
        -ms-zoom: 0.5;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
</style>

<iframe id="frame" src="example.com" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Above is my current HTML code, working fine but I can't seem to get it centered on the page, it just sits on the left. I am looking to do this without a css file, so that I can use it in a widget with ease, although Im not sure what to change in  to get it moving. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, you can do this by setting the iFrame position to absolute and top and left to 50%. As shown below:

```
<iframe id="frame" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;" src="example.com" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```